# problem with creating variables in For-Loop in R , working with EDGAR

Tags: r

I am new to R programming and I would appreciate some help.

I am working with the package EDARWebR but I guess my question is a generic R programming question.

I need to create a data frame containing information about firms 10-K forms.

the functions that I use are company_filings and filing_filers.

```
apple_filings = company_filings("0000320193", type = "10-K", page = 1000 )
```

the first input is a company identifier called `CIK`.

the above code returns a data frame in which each row is the detail of a 10K submission by Apple Inc. including the link to the SEC webpage for each submission.

then I can use this link as input for filing_filers to get information about Apple in that specific year which is my end goal:

```
filing_filers("web_address_from_company_filings")
```

I need to write a code that goes through different companies and returns a data frame where each row is output from filing_filers for a specific company in a specific year.

I have written the following code:

```
# cik_sample is a char vector of my firm identifiers
cik_sample = c("0001438823","0000320193","0000018230" )

for (j in cik_sample){
    c_filings = company_filings(j, type = "10-K",count = 1000  )
    row_num = nrow(c_filings)

# in case the cik doesn't return anything:  
    if (row_num == 0){
        next
    }
#keep what I need
    c_filings_short = select(c_filings, filing_date, href, type)
# store the links, which I need for filing_filers function  
    c_hrefs <- as.data.frame(c_filings_short[,2])
#setting up for the loop
    c_length = length(c_hrefs)
    c_index = (1:c_length)

# creating an empty data frame to be filled in with loop  
# name the variable using cik identifier
    nam <- paste("cik_", j,sep="")
    assign(nam, data.frame(matrix(ncol =21, nrow = c_length )))  

    for (i in c_index) { 
        nam[i,] <- filing_filers(as.character(c_hrefs[i,1]))
    }
}
```

my problem is with the last loop. it's giving me the error :

```
Error in nam[i, ] <- filing_filers(as.character(c_hrefs[i, 1])) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

so the code does create cik_0000320193 correctly, 
and I think I understand why variable nam is a character and not a data frame and that is because, in the assign function, nam is just a placeholder.
But I don't know what to do to fill out the empty cik_xxxxxxxxxx in each iteration.
Also, can you please help me attach all the data frame together in one big data frame containing data from al companies?

since I am very new to R, I had to resort to writing a couple of loops. I don't know if there are more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. package names are case sensitive so be sure to spell the package name as shown below.
2. it is normally undesirable to create a set of related variables floating loosely in your workspace but rather it is preferable to create a list to hold them all using `lapply` or `Map` to create the list.
3. `nam` is a character string and the `nam[i, ] <- ...`  statement is attempting to subscript the character string as if it were a data frame.  The object  that was created in the `assign` has a name such as `cik_0000320193`, not `nam`.  If you really wanted to assign to that object it would be `.GlobalEnv[[nam]][i, ] <- ...`; however, we will follow (2) above.

First create a function `get10K` to get the filings for one cik and then use `Map` to apply it to each cik.  Finally use `Filter` to remove the empty components.  This gives a list of data frames.

```
library(edgarWebR)

get10K <- function(cik) {
  c_filings <- company_filings(cik, type = "10-K", count = 1000  )
  cbind(do.call("rbind", lapply(c_filings$href, filing_filers)), 
    filing_date = c_filings$filing_date)
}

res <- Filter(length, Map(get10K, cik_sample))
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly and it was so elegant. I have so much to learn. I just noticed that I need the filing_date as the end result doesn't have any date column. So beside href from company_filings, I need to keep the filing_date for each href. I would appreciate your help with that as well.

Comment: OK. Have added.

Comment: Thanks again; so I would like to order the columns to bring the company name and filing date to the beginning.  I have searched online and I found the most basic way of doing it which is filing_date = c_filings$filing_date)[c(9,22,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)]
}  is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: `res` is a list of data frames.  If you want to sort each of them then `lapply(res, function(x) x[order(x$filing_date), ] )`